# Java Applet works in Firefox only

Tags: java, browser, deployment, applet

I have implemented a Java Applet.
I have exported the jar.
I signed the jar.
And it works if I put it on my server and use it with HTML.
But only in Firefox.

Here is the HTML:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!DOCTYPE html
  PUBLIC "//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<title>Upload Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <object archive="applet.jar" classid="java:uploader/FileUpload.class"
    codetype="application/java-vm" width="800" height="600"> </object>

</body>
</html>
```

I also tried it with this:

```html
<SCRIPT type="text/javascript">
if(browser.value.getIndex("chrome") {
  chrome.browser.enableFeature(JApplet)
});
</SCRIPT>
```

But still Firefox only.
I would really like for this to work in Chrome & IE9.
But these two only leave a space where the Applet should be.
I can even highlight it.

Are there things I have to add in my xhtml? Or maybe something in the Applet?

I found enough online about why Applets might not work, but nothing about why Firefox only.

Comment: Are you seeing any errors in Chrome/IE9 debug tools?

Comment: In Chrome/IE is there a placeholder (ie white box) where the applet should be or just nothing?

Comment: There is a Placeholder, yes.
I read that Chrome is 32bit and Java7 is 64bit, which might lead to problems?

Comment: Use [`deployJava.js`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/deployment_advice.html) to write the applet element compatible with each browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Andrew Thompson said, I need to use deployJava.js.
You can find it in [this Oracle tutorial.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/deployingApplet.html)
This tutorial describes in detail every step neccessary.

Now my Applet works on all three browsers (FF, Chrome, IE9) like a charm.

Thanks!

Comment: I think everybody knows how frustrating it is, when you find someone with your exact problem, but he doesn't report, if he could find an answer :D